# Impossible to solve Sharepoint dropdown behavior

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am currently experiencing some very weird dropdown menu behavior in Sharepoint.

## Summary of the error:

Dropdowns don't work on the page after Ctrl+R to refresh the page. If I click in the address bar and hit enter the dropdowns work.

## How to reproduce the error:

- Go to the website: http://www.jdaihelpdesk.org/default.aspx
- Mouse over one of the menu items at the top, dropdown items **will** appear.
- However, if you hit Ctrl+R to reload the page, when you mouse over one of the menu items, the dropdown **will no longer** appear.
- Even weirder, if you open up developer tools and put a breakpoint on line 5 of the resource file titled http://www.jdaihelpdesk.org/ScriptResource.axd?d=mp6tevUL8oeNESOYJzVjF4zt3gpf2XdWLbE3BbLBQDYBVZVAQp00gRgopkUa1x9lC9s-iuzbDatvYvVbz7xnHLXzyr_vbt6Y91YZqrMVq_6N-PshJk3rZnu9fGlYq2Z8x9XfJo4ZhLF5WQffpPe1KcOEZvI1&t=2e2045e2
  , hit Ctrl+R to refresh the page, after hitting continue, the menu item **will** work.

So it's like there's something to do with when resources are getting loaded or something but that's just a guess after hours of looking at this issue.

What's also weird to me is that hitting Ctrl+R will cause the dropdowns to not appear but clicking in the address bar and hitting Enter to load the page, the dropdowns will appear.

If anybody has any insights that would be awesome!

Comment: Have you tried debugging in Sharepoint designer?

Comment: Have you thought about rebuilding the site using a different CMS? Seems like a pretty simple site to be using such fully featured collaboration software like SharePoint.

Comment: When I refresh your homepage with ctrl-R, the dropdowns work. I'm using IE10.

Comment: @PhilGreer Thanks for looking into this! I am testing in Chrome. But you're right I just tried it in IE10 and it worked...so weird. I am baffled by this behavior!

Comment: in IE 11 also it works fine

Comment: I don't know if you fixed this, but I am using Chrome and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in Chrome that is caused by a piece of JavaScript that runs on body onload.
Chrome fires that event before some of the SharePoint scripts are ready to be used, for which the ribbon, scrollbars and other script dependent features do not work properly.
If you "own" the Master page, you can overcome this by placing the same body onload script inside jQuery $(document).ready event (which fires later and same for all browsers).

Reference: 
http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/256